# How to index geojson data in browser to store in indexDB (using geojson-vt)

Tags: gis, mapbox, geojson, turfjs, rxdb

#### Overview

I have a fairly interesting requirement where I need to load geojson data from a service (not a vector tile service) and then cache that data for offline use (using indexDB). So, when running the application offline I need to load that data from indexDB into the map (using mapbox-gl). The amount of data that could be cached offline (in indexDB) could be quite large and therefore I cannot just bring all of the data into memory and add it to the map (in which case mapbox would handle everything for us internally using geojson-vt).

I realize that if the source was a vector tile service that would make things easier, but unfortunately that is not an option at this point in time.

#### Attempted Solution

I believe the solution to this problem is to index the data when I store it in indexDB. My thought was that I would figure out each of the UTM grid values for each "feature" and that way when the map moves I can simply query the features in the respective grid(s) and load them into mapbox.

**Example IndexDB "Table":**

```
feature_id | properties | utm_tiles ({z}_{x}_{y})
1               ...       14_0_0, 13_1_1, 13_1_2, etc
2               ...       14_0_0, 12_100_100, 12_100_101, etc
etc...
```

Have the info above I could then query 
select * from index_db_features where utm_tiles in ('14_0_0', '14_0_1')

While this theoretically seems like it would work, the problem I am having is figuring out all of the tiles that a given feature touches. The [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt/issues) library seems to do what I want except it doesn't give you an actual list of all tiles that the feature(s) are found in - it does the reverse, where you need to ask it for features based on a given tile.

Does anyone have any suggestions for finding out what all tiles a given feature touches? Or a better suggestion for spatially indexing geojson data for use in indexDB?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current solution to this problem:

1. Add a `location` object with `location.lat`, `location.lon` fields to the `properties` of each geojson feature (I'm using the center of the feature).
2. Create a compound index in IndexDB (I'm using dexie.js) for `location.lon` and `location.lng`
3. Query the IndexDB database to find all the features that are inside the visible screen (or add padding if needed)

Basically:

```js
// Create DB:
let db = new Dexie("features");
db.version(1).stores({
    pois: "properties.id,[properties.location.lat+properties.location.lon]"
});
// Adding:
db.table("pois").bulkPut(someGeojsonFeaturesArray);
// Getting:
function getFeatures(northEast, southWest): Promise<GeoJSON.Feature[]> {
        return db.table("pois")
            .where("[properties.location.lat+properties.location.lon]")
            .between([southWest.lat, southWest.lon], [northEast.lat, northEast.lon])
            .toArray();
    }
```

This works and is scalable but I think tiled data should work faster.
Feel free to add your comment to this Github Issue:
https://github.com/IsraelHikingMap/Site/issues/1169

See implementation here:
https://github.com/IsraelHikingMap/Site/blob/e31e4e73107897c9e069f1426ca9d56f13cf7bff/IsraelHiking.Web/sources/application/services/database.service.ts#L30